# How can I sort alphanumeric in string

Tags: javascript

How can I sort only alphanumeric of my string, 'Hello, world'.sort(6) must return Hello...

```
String.prototype.sort = function(num){
  if (this.toString().length <= num) {
    return this.toString();

  }
  return this.toString().slice(0, num) + '...';
}
//   var str = this.toString().slice(0,num) + '...';
//   for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
//     char = str.charAt(i);
//     if(char.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) == null) {
//       str = str.slice(0,i) + str.slice(i+1);
//   }
// }
console.log('Hello, world!'.sort(6));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is this sort or truncate?

Comment: 'sort' is the wrong word. Use the word 'truncate'.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to filter? What do you mean when you say "sort only alphanumeric of string"?

Comment: yes it's truncate

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to truncate your string, don't bother trying to implement your own function, just provide the start and end indexes to this method:

```js
console.log('Hello, world!'.substring(0, 6));
```